# Combining 2 parquets that are too large for memory together

Tags: r, parquet, apache-arrow

Say I have two datasets stored as parquets that I want to combine. I can read them in, `rbind` them, then spit them back out into a parquet, like so:

```r
# Load library
library(arrow)

# Create dummy datasets
write_dataset(mtcars, path = "~/foo", format = "parquet")
write_dataset(mtcars, path = "~/bar", format = "parquet")

# Read, combine, and write datasets
open_dataset("~/foo") |> collect() -> foo
open_dataset("~/bar") |> collect() -> bar
rbind(foo, bar) |> write_dataset(path = "~/foobar", format = "parquet")
```

That's great! Now, imagine that these datasets are so large that I don't have enough memory to hold *both* datasets in my R session. How would I go about combining these datasets into one?

Comment: You may find [This posting](https://community.rstudio.com/t/appending-to-parquet-file-with-arrow/68383) helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to use the internal or granular functions in the `arrow` package to take apart and iterate over the data, but (1) I'm not certain it's possible, and (2) I think it is not necessary.

You can combine them virtually by calling `open_dataset` on both files:

```r
arrow::write_dataset(data.frame(A=1:2), "A.pq")
arrow::write_dataset(data.frame(A=3:4), "B.pq")

list.files(c("A.pq", "B.pq"), full.names = TRUE)
# [1] "A.pq/part-0.parquet" "B.pq/part-0.parquet"

ds <- arrow::open_dataset(list.files(c("A.pq", "B.pq"), full.names = TRUE))
collect(ds)
#   A
# 1 1
# 2 2
# 3 3
# 4 4
```

That is, `open_dataset` can take as its first argument (`sources=`) one of (from `?arrow::open_dataset`):

- a string path or URI to a directory containing data files
- a FileSystem that references a directory containing data
  files (such as what is returned by 's3_bucket()')
- a string path or URI to a single file
- a character vector of paths or URIs to individual data
  files
- a list of 'Dataset' objects as created by this function
- a list of 'DatasetFactory' objects as created by
  'dataset_factory()'.

and my method takes advantage of the fourth bullet. (It doesn't take a vector of multiple directories, which is why we need to intervene with `list.files`.)

*Edit*: the lazy operation of `arrow` (and `dplyr`'s help) allows us to "load" all of the frames into an apparent object without loading the data into memory. For instance, if we wanted just the even rows, using dplyr we would do

```r
library(dplyr)
filter(ds, A %% 2 == 0)
# FileSystemDataset (query)
# A: int32
# * Filter: (subtract_checked(A, multiply_checked(2, floor(divide(cast(A, {to_type=double, allow_int_overflow=false, allow_time_truncate=false, allow_time_overflow=false, allow_decimal_truncate=false, allow_float_truncate=false, allow_invalid_utf8=false}), cast(2, {to_type=double, allow_int_overflow=false, allow_time_truncate=false, allow_time_overflow=false, allow_decimal_truncate=false, allow_float_truncate=false, allow_invalid_utf8=false}))))) == 0)
# See $.data for the source Arrow object
```

Which *still* has not loaded the data into memory. For that we use `collect()`, which is the first time that the raw data in the parquet files is pulled into R.

```r
filter(ds, A %% 2 == 0) %>%
  collect()
#   A
# 1 2
# 2 4
```

Comment: Whoa - that's super interesting. Instead of collecting at the end, if I wrote straight to disk, e.g., `arrow::open_dataset(...) |> arrow::write_dataset(...)`, would that actually mean neither is actually loaded into my session as such?

Comment: One of the benefits of using arrow's "lazy" operation is that you don't actually pull all of the data into memory until you call `collect`, so having combined sets of data that would (if pulled en toto) be too large for RAM is not a problem, filter down (and/or aggregate/summarize) as needed before calling `collect()`.

Comment: (I think you already understand the _need_ for `collect`, not sure about the power/flexibility of pre-collect processing. Did I miss your point?)

Comment: Thanks for this! My question was just that I don't actually _need_ it in memory at the moment (i.e., no collect required), so can I pipe it straight back out after combining the two without having ever having to collect? I think your answer was, yes, that's fine.

Comment: I haven't tried that, but I don't _think_ it's designed to work that way. However ... feel free to try it and report back if your R exhausts memory. (I don't have parquet files big-enough to do that to me and don't want to contrive it ... the one time 64GB of ram is haunting me :-)

Comment: I don't know the R interface as well as I should but that is how datasets were designed to work.  For example, a common task is to read a dataset consisting of hundreds of CSV files and write it out as parquet.  I agree with @r2evans that you probably don't want or need to combine two parquet files into a larger parquet file.  Unless your parquet files are really small there isn't much penalty to having two files.

Comment: Memory usage in such a scenario is tricky.  Arrow will process the datasets in a streaming fashion.  But right now the parquet scanner is limited in that it has to read data 1 row group at a time.  In addition, by default, Arrow is going to try and read from multiple files at the same time.  If each of your parquet files has a single row group then you will probably still run out of RAM.

Comment: The only time I would consider combining parquet files (and this is something I do periodically on a datamart I maintain) is when the number of parquet files for a particular (specific!) dataset becomes so large so as to adversely affect the indexing and loading of data within arrow. For instance, reading a few files is fine, but reading a hundred or so files like this will show a slow-down. This can be mitigated somewhat with `unify_schemas=FALSE`, but at some point it makes sense to bite the bullet (if able) to reduce the number of files.

Comment: However, if the row groups in your input parquet files are small enough then you should be ok but it's still going to use all your RAM while the operation is in progress.  Your OS will generally implement a "write" asynchronously by copying the data from user space to a kernel space buffer in the OS' cache.  It will only actually start blocking when you've filled up that cache which usually means you've run out of RAM.

Comment: Yes, compaction if you have too many files is a good use case too.